# Route в Backbone.Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, html5-history-api, route, marionette.js

Здравствуйте. Обнаружил странное поведение роутов

У меня есть пара роутов вида:

```
/vehicles
/vehicles/:id
/vehicles/:id/:someAction
```

Если я находясь на любой странице, захожу на

```
/vehicles/:id/:someAction
```

а потом нажимаю назад, то он переходит не на предыдущую страницу, а на

```
/vehicles/:id
```

Даже не могу предположить, почему так, ведь всё же идёт через History API

```
Backbone.VERSION = "1.1.2"
Marionette.VERSION = "2.2.0"
```

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте, не забыли лы вы после создания роутера вызвать бэкбоновский обработчик событий **hashchange** :

```
 var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes : {
        'vehicles(/)' : 'vehicles',              // #vehicles
        'vehicles/:id(/)' : 'vehicle',           // #vehicles/123
        'vehicles/:id/:someAction(/)' : 'action' // #vehicles/123/show
    },
    vehicles : function () {
        console.log('vehicles');
    },
    vehicle : function (id) {
        console.log('vehicles', id);
    },
    action : function (id, someAction) {
        console.log('vehicles', id, someAction);
    }
});
var router = new Router();

Backbone.history.start(/* { pushState : true } */); // <- не забыть!
```

Так же обратите внимание на то, что роуты в хэше **routes** не должны начинаться с '/'. Ключ **pushState** для History API

Comment: routes не начинаются с /, pushState у меня выставлен. Вот часть кода роутов:
http://jsfiddle.net/wmj2jgm9/1/

Comment: За неимением лучших ответов, баунти едет сюда)

Answer (score 0):

Немного покопался в интернете и нашел следующее:

В стандартном пакете имеется `add-on` который делает такой глюк.

Предлагают удалить библиотеку `rails/turbolinks` который мешает обновлении страницы.

Переписали `fiddle` и все работает. [Вот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Seabiscuit/yaz9x2o7/1/).

Оригинал взял из [stackoverflow.com на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27831759/4953620)

Comment: Извините, я что-то не понял, при чём тут вообще рельсы?) Там сервер на рельсах, у меня локальный на node, а в проде на JVM.

Тем более, разве не это History API всё это разруливает?

Comment: Извините, в вопросе не было этих платформ, вот и я не правильно понял. Может по подробнее скажете что у вас там и как ?

Comment: В том-то и дело, что у меня там ничего сверхъестественного не делается. Узким моментом может быть

http://jsfiddle.net/wmj2jgm9/1/